# Difference between java run and Netbeans run

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I am confused with the below two commands

1. Java -jar ABCProj.jar
2. ant -f D:\NetBeansProjects\ABCProj jfxsa-run

The reason is my application is working fine if I go run in netbeans using point 2. But when I run in command program using point1, my application is not working properly.

Please suggest.

Thanks
Srikanth

Comment: *my application is not working properly* **define**

Comment: I have developed a small JavaFX application which will call the other Java based application using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); in a separate thread.

I have tested my application using Netbeans it is working properly.

When I try to execute the same in command line using the below statement: java - jar Myprogram.jar. I am able to launch the application but the call of Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd) code is not executed.

Please suggest if I am missing something when trying to execute using cmd line

Comment: The values I am passing for cmd are as shown: java -cp <classpath> -javaagent:./lib/MyAgent.jar=arg1